# Dynamic search bar suggestions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I want to display different words (e.g. city names)in the searchbar before the user even types something to inspire him what to search for.

Like here: https://mapify.travel/

Any ideas how to do it?

right now my code is this

```
<%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5" style=" left: 22%;">
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: " z.B. Berlin", class: "suchfeld", id: "autolocation" %>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2" style="margin-left: 290px;">
        <%= submit_tag "search", class: "btnsearch" %>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: You already seem to be using a placeholder, which is what the site you link to is doing, so I'm not sure what the issue is..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this maybe... where `#email` is the id of the text field input.

This also assumed that the first item in the array `arry` is the value of the default placeholder value. If you do not want to set a hardcoded default placeholder value in your html then you can just programtically set the placeholder on document load.

```
setInterval(function(){
  var arry = ['example@example.com', 'placeholder 2', 'placeholder 3', 'placeholder 4']
  $this = $('#email')
  var old_placeholder       = $this.attr('placeholder')
  var old_placeholder_index = arry.indexOf(old_placeholder)
  var new_placeholder_index = (old_placeholder_index + 1) % arry.length

  $this.attr('placeholder', arry[new_placeholder_index])
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways you could do this with varying levels of complexity.

A simple way to do this would be to store all the options for locations you want to preemptively appear in an array or object, and when the user selects the search box, randomly pick a few of them to suggest to the user.